# Elasticbeanstalk - NGINX - 413 Request entity too large

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-413

I know this might be considered a duplicate of: [Customizing Nginx Configuration in AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202625/customizing-nginx-configuration-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk) (and other questions), but I was unable to make my code work with any of the proposed solutions.

This is how my config.yml file looks like (xxx = environment name):

```
branch-defaults:
    master:
        environment: xxx
    environment-defaults:
      xxx:
        branch: master
        repository: xxx
    global:
      application_name: xxx
      default_ec2_keyname: null
      default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1::platform/Node.js running on
        64bit Amazon Linux/4.3.0
      default_region: eu-west-1
      instance_profile: null
      platform_name: null
      platform_version: null
      profile: null
      sc: git
      workspace_type: Application
```

Then adding:

```
http:
  files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
          http {
            client_max_body_size 20M;
          }
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

For allowing bigger payloads and trying to restart nginx to accept the changes after deploy. However, even though it seems the accepted method it is not working in my code. Everything else works perfectly fine with smaller files than 1mb.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to increase client_max_body_size to 50M ?

Comment: I was sending a file of 3mb. Do you think 20 vs. 50 makes a difference there?

Comment: @JanRuno did you find any solution?

Comment: 1. Open `.ebextensions` and verify nginx config file name. It must end with `.config`. 2. Verify that `.ebextensions` content is copied inside app package. 3. ssh to ec2 instance and verify that file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` is created after deployment.

Comment: 4. `.ebextensions` should be placed in the root of the app package.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add **EC2InstanceConnect** permission to your EC2 User after that set **client_max_body_size 20M;** in EC2 **nginx.conf** file.(you may increase client_max_body_size according your requirement)

-Go to your AWS console

-Search IAM user and go user group that is assign to your user

-In the add permission tab click on Attach policies

-Search EC2InstanceConnect policy and attach it.

**Edit the nginx.conf file and reload nginx**

-You will find the nginx.conf file under etc/nginx. This is how you get to etc from where you start.

-Once you are in etc/nginx write **sudo nano nginx.conf** in the command line.(This opens up the nginx.conf file and enables editing)

-In ngnx.conf file under **server** Add the line **client_max_body_size 20M;** (or whatever limit suits you)
Save your changes and exit the file(ctrl+s, ctrl+x)

-head to sbin which is on the same level as etc and run command **sudo nginx -s reload**

Now check again, most probably your issued was solved.